# How do you get EC2 instance's ssh user using boto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

On AWS console, after clicking an instance, I can use **Connect** to see what user the instance can be connected with (although this may not be accurate).

For rough estimation, I want to know if I can get this using boto or not (I know I can guess the username based on the popular image/OS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this.  There is no API from EC2 that provides this information.  I suppose you could come up with some heuristics based on the underlying AMI that would be right most of the time.  For example, lookup the `image_id` associated with an instance and then look at the `name`, `location`, and `description` values and compare to some table of data and make a guess.  As far as I know, nothing like that exists right now.

Comment: Yeah :( wish they would expose this even at the guess level. Thanks.

Comment: Its one of many, many bits of metadata that I wish I could get programmatically from AWS.  Maybe one of these days.

Comment: you can use tags, example:  i usually create all instances by tag user = ec2-user by default , exceptionally i rename the user if required.